# word suggestions control for windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, autocomplete, word-completion

Does anyone know how to implement a word suggestion popup menu so that when you type letters it will open up popu menu and suggest words that you can choose from and when chosen you can continue typing much like the word suggestion in for example text messages.
This feature is already in windows phone 8 if you put the input scope for Textblock to Text but the problem is that you can't input your own words to the dictionary programatically.
I was also looking at the autocomplete for windows phone 8 toolkit but the problem there is that you can't continue typing after you have selected the word from list. Any idea how to modify that control so that you can do it ?

Thanks,
Jani

Answer (score 0):

You need an AutocompleteBox, this article should help you http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_Auto_Complete_Box_in_Windows_Phone

Comment: I was looking at that but it works a bit differently than what i want. When you choose a word from the list you can't continue typing in the box anymore. I would need to modify the control. Do you know is the source code for the control available?